# Iterar um array (vetor) via IEnumerator? Por qual razão?

Tags: c#, .net, array

Em que caso faria sentido eu abrir mão de iterar um *array* usando *loops*
"normais" (`for/foreach/while`) **via índice** para utilizar a `IEnumerator` como mostrado no Exemplo 3?

#### Exemplo1

```
//Usando for
    int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };     
    for ( int i = 0; i < array.Lenght; i++)
    {    
      Console.WriteLine( array[i] );     
    }
```

#### Exemplo2

```
//Usando foreach (Na prática o compilador gera um código bem parecido ao Exemplo1)
    int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};     
    foreach (int item in array) 
    {       
      Console.WriteLine(item);     
    }
```

#### Exemplo3

```
//Via IEnumerator utilizando o loop while
      int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
      IEnumerator o = array.GetEnumerator();
      while (o.MoveNext())
      {
        Console.WriteLine(o.Current);    
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você sabe que é um *array* e é um laço simples não vejo razão alguma para usar `IEnumerator`.

Se quiser generalizar a implementação e aceitar outras coisas que não seja um *array* como detalhe de implementação, aí usar um `IEnumerable` pode ser interessante, mas isto seria usado em algo que não saiba o que virá, então seria um parâmetro ou o retorno de um método. Mas não faz sentido no exemplo mostrado.

Se quiser ter um controle a enumeração fora do laço básico também pode ser interessante. Com um enumerador é possível transportar o estado da enumeração para outros locais do código, passando como argumento de um método, retorná-lo no método atual, armazenar como membro de algum objeto, etc. É raro precisar algo assim, mas é uma forma de fazer coisas mais complexas. Com a varredura pelo índice o estado da enumeração só existe dentro do laço.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class Program {
    static int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
    public static void Main() {
        var o = Teste();
        if (o != null) {
            WriteLine("Continuando...");
            while (o.MoveNext()) WriteLine(o.Current);
        }
    }
    static IEnumerator Teste() {
        IEnumerator o = array.GetEnumerator();
        while (o.MoveNext()) {
            WriteLine(o.Current);
            if ((int)o.Current > 2) return o;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9bAsxZ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hNU4a5). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/Enumerator.cs).

[Se o .NET fosse escrito hoje seria diferente](http://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2014/08/19/rethinking-enumerable.html).